# Each input letter is returned on individual line

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

As the title suggests, I want each letter enter into the input field to be displayed on a new line using a while loop. For example if someone enters 'cat' in the input box this would be returned:

c

a

t

This is what I have so far, but at the moment its only displaying the first letter.

```
 var input = document.getElementById('userinput').value;
  var i  = input.length;
  while (i--) {
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = (input[i]);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = (input[i]);
```

Is completely overwriting the HTML of the `#message` element, so it will only have the value of the last iteration. Instead you will want do:

```
document.getElementById('message').innerHTML += (input[i]) + "<br />";
```

With the `<br />` moving to a new line. To have it in a top-down fashion you may want to use a normal for-loop instead:

```
for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML += input[i] + "<br />";
```

---

Below is a basic snippet example (*hitting enter or unfocusing will trigger the event*):

```js
document.getElementById('text').addEventListener("change", function(){
  document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "";
  input = document.getElementById('text').value;
  for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
      document.getElementById('message').innerHTML += input[i] + "<br />";
});
```

```html
<input id="text" type="text" />
<div id="message"></div>
```

Comment: thanks this works perfectly! Just so i can learn, how come when i use the while loop, the input is returned in reverse (down-up)?

Comment: Because your while loop starts on the last character and goes to the first character on the last iteration, where this for-loop is starting at the first and going to the last character.

Comment: Note that as a general principle it is better to build up the desired output in a variable and then assign once to `.innerHTML` after the loop - the fewer updates to the DOM the better. (Also, there's nothing wrong with loops, but I'd use `.innerHTML = input.split("").join("<br>")`.)

Comment: Also, "<br />" is a hangover from XHTML. It might be preferred by some IDEs because parsing XML is simpler than HTML, but in a browser the HTML parser just sees the " /" as junk.

Comment: ahh thanks for clarifying! Just curious, is there a way to use the while loop without it reversing the input?